# Changing the documentation for re-exported types and values

Tags: haskell, haddock

Suppose I have a module which re-exports a value from an internal module:

```
module My.Cool.Module (SomeType, someValue) where
import My.Cool.Module.Internal (SomeType, someValue)
```

I'd like to show different documentation for `SomeType` and `someValue` in `My-Cool-Module.html` and `My-Cool-Module-Internal.html`, so the former can discuss the public API and the latter can discuss how they relate to the rest of internals.

Is there a way to do this with haddock?

I tried:

```
module My.Cool.Module (SomeType, someValue) where
import My.Cool.Module.Internal
  ( SomeType -- ^ a serious type for serious people
  , someValue -- ^ a serious value for serious people
  )
```

But haddock gave me a parse error:

```
parse error on input ‘-- ^ a serious type for serious people’
```

Comment: can't you instead of reexporting the function , just redefine it ? I mean import `Internal` qualified and define `someType = Internal.someType`. That should allow you to add you own documentation.

Comment: mb14: seems like a good idea. redefining types seems problematic though.

Comment: You are right, I didn't realize you were also asking about Type.

Comment: mb14: I'd still toss an upvote your way if you made that into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here's a hack that I can live with.

Haddock allows you to insert [named chunks of documentation](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/ch03s05.html), which are shown in the order they're defined. These named chunks are only shown for the module they're in, not in any file that re-exports values or types from that module.

So in the internal module, I can insert named chunks containing the internal documentation right after the public API documentation:

```
-- | Have you welcomed internal modules into your life?
module Public.Private where

-- | Here's the public API information for 'SomeType'
type SomeType = ()
-- $
-- Here's the internal information about 'SomeType': it's really just a stand-in
-- for San Francisco

-- | Here's the public API information for 'someValue'
someValue :: SomeType
-- $ Here's the internal information about 'someValue': it loves cheese.
someValue = ()
```

and then export the types and values as normal

```
-- | This is a very serious public API
module Public ( SomeType, someValue) where
import Public.Private ( SomeType , someValue)
```

Now the generated documentation for `Public.Private` shows the internal documentation right after the public documentation:

[image: Generated HTML documentation for Public.Private]

While the `Public` documentation for the exported items doesn't show the internal documentation:

[image: Generated HTML documentation for Public]

This only allows me to append private documentation, but that's better than nothing.